# Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining' running expo dev client

Tags: javascript, react-native, babeljs

When I make the updates

```
react-native-gesture-handler  ~2.10.2 -> ~2.12.0
react-native-get-random-values  ~1.8.0 -> ~1.9.0 
react-native-reanimated  ~3.1.0 -> ~3.3.0
react-native-screens  ~3.20.0 -> ~3.21.1
```

in my `package.json` I get the error

> Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining'

when I `yarn expo start --dev-client --ios`.

To address the error I've tried adding [the entire `peerDependencies` section](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/blob/2426f32095af417f1cfc1789479c3d2ee7c72e18/package.json#L86-L95) [suggested on a related issue](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/4538), but still get the same error.

Why am I getting this error and how to I prevent it?

---

```json
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.22.5",
    "@config-plugins/react-native-ble-plx": "^6.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/pro-duotone-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/sharp-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.18.2",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.10",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.10",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^6.3.0",
    "aws-amplify": "^5.3.0",
    "aws-amplify-react-native": "^7.0.2",
    "expo": "^48.0.19",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.2.1",
    "expo-file-system": "~15.2.2",
    "expo-sharing": "~11.2.2",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "expo-updates": "~0.16.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.11",
    "react-native-ble-plx": "^2.0.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.10.2",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "~1.8.0",
    "react-native-logs": "^5.0.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.1.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.5",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.0",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.5",
    "@redux-devtools/core": "^3.13.1",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.2",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.13",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.25",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.60.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.60.0",
    "eslint": "^8.43.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^27.2.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "jest-expo": "^48.0.2",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  ...
```

```js
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true)
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin']
  }
}
```

Comment: Run yarn add @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining after that run yarn expo start --dev-client --ios if you get another error like this about anyother package please install that too